# Java, Why can ExecutorService::executor() execute funciton that do not implement Runnable interface?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

This is more of a theoretical question. I recently created a simple multithreading application in java, and I used ExecutorService to run and manage threads. The way I start my threads is very simple, I create a function in my class and then I send this function as parameter to ExecutorService::execute() function like this:

```
public void foo(){ 
   //method code here
}

myExecutor.execute(this::foo);
```

But as you can notice I did not implement a Runnable interface anywhere, and I do not have a run() method, yet this method works. From what I read, the object passed to execute function should be a Runnable with a run() method ([see execute documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute(java.lang.Runnable))). Could someone explain why is my method working, and if it is really necessary to have a "Runnable" object when my method works?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the :: operator (method reference operator) is a shorthand for a lambda function, which is a Runnable, and could be written like this:

```
myExecutor.execute(() -> foo());
```

Comment: Ohhh, thanks a lot, I have seen some code using it this way (with lambda), I did not realize that a lambda function is a Runnable, thanks a lot!

Comment: @asdzx some lambdas are Runnable, not all of them.